# why this code only save first pic while i am selection more the 1

Tags: c#, picturebox

in above code i have selected multiple images with picturebox TimesSelect and showed in panel ,panel show all selected images but in database only first pictures multiple time e.g i select 10 pic , in database first Picture is saved 10 time

```
if (files != null)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Avais\Desktop\GUI of GUA\GUI of GUA\GUAdatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

    con.Open();
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(files[0], System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);

    byte[] image = new byte[fs.Length];
    fs.Read(image, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));

    fs.Close();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Admin_Pic_Lib(Pictures) VALUES (@pic)", con);
    SqlParameter prm = new SqlParameter("@pic", SqlDbType.VarBinary, image.Length, ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 0, null, DataRowVersion.Current, image);

    cmd.Parameters.Add(prm);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    label1.ForeColor = Color.Green;
    label1.Text = "Pic Added Suscussfully";

    con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently only targeting the first image / file that is available :

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(files[0], ...);
```

If you want to target and save multiple files, consider looping through your files collection and performing this operation for each of them :

```
foreach(var file in files)
{
        // Read each individual file and save it here
}
```

Comment: can please explain it with some detail

Comment: What part are you having difficulties with? Your current `files` collection consists of one or more files, so you'll need to iterate through this collection and add each one into the database within the body of the `foreach` loop.